# Assigning graphics a "type"

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to programming so please excuse me for not being very technical. Is there any way to make the following line of code produce a value so I can assign a name to it?

```
Dim myGraphics as Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
myGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, 0, 0, 300, 10)
```

for example I would want the code to be

```
topWall = myGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, 0 , 0, 300, 10)
```

I know I could use a rectangle instead for this but I was just looking to know if there is a way to do this. I hope this makes sense. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No, you are drawing directly on the Graphics object. My thought would be why do you need it? An option might be that you save a certain structure in a local class that can then be painted towards some kind of Graphics object. I guess you would like to draw based on some previous position of another object? Or you wish to manipulate previously drawn items?

Comment: Ahh I see, yes that makes sense! I'm making something similar to a maze game, where if a picturebox collides with myGraphics it won't go any further.

Comment: Yes, then it would be easier if you could compare the positions with a local dataset, and only draw to your graphics when you have actually something to draw. If you would expand your question with why you would need this and what you could do to make it work (maybe with some tryout code), I am sure people would be able to help you